# keeping changed color after refresh

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

i'm trying to change my head and button color using this code

```
   <div class="ann-right">
    <button id="red" onclick="color1('#D91E18'), color2('#96281B')" class="tooltip color" title="Red"></button>
    <button id="green" onclick="color1('#3FC380'), color2('#00B16A')" class="tooltip color"title="Green" ></button>
    <button id="blue" onclick="color1('#5BBBFF'), color2('#22A7F0')" class="tooltip color" title="Blue"></button>
   </div>

  <script>
  function color1(col){
  document.getElementById("head").style.backgroundColor=col;
  }

  function color2(col){
  document.getElementById("submit-search").style.backgroundColor=col;
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor=col;
  }
  </script>
```

How to keep the color after the page refreshed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208572/changing-background-colour-with-javascript-and-keeping-it-after-refreshing-the-p | i tried to use this. but still ain't keep the color..

Comment: Where are the elements you're trying to style, those with the id of `head` and `submit-search`?

Comment: @DavidThomas `submit-search` and `submit-post` for the button and exactly `head` for `id="head"`, The color succesfully changed, but what i try to ask is how do i keep the changed color after i refresh the page ?

Comment: Indeed; but not having those elements in the HTML you posted means you haven't followed, and perhaps haven't read, the [mcve] guidelines, *not* posting that code means that we're having to try and guess where those elements are in your HTML which means we're doing unnecessary work in order to try and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options to implement the required behavior, one of which is to use sessionStorage. Save the selected color in sessionStorgae and read it on page load. Refer to the following for more info:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

**Update**: For your case:

```html
<div class="ann-right">
  <button id="red" onclick="color1('#D91E18'), color2('#96281B')" class="tooltip color" title="Red"></button>
  <button id="green" onclick="color1('#3FC380'), color2('#00B16A')" class="tooltip color" title="Green"></button>
  <button id="blue" onclick="color1('#5BBBFF'), color2('#22A7F0')" class="tooltip color" title="Blue"></button>
</div>

<script>
  function color1(col) {
    document.getElementById("head").style.backgroundColor = col;
    sessionStorage.setItem('col1', col);
  }

  function color2(col) {
    document.getElementById("submit-search").style.backgroundColor = col;
    document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = col;
    sessionStorage.setItem('col2', col);
  }

  color1(sessionStorage.getItem('col1'));
  color2(sessionStorage.getItem('col2'));
</script>
```

Comment: If your answer becomes almost meaningless when the external content to which you've linked dies, is moved or reorganised, that's a hint that you should - at the *very least* - summarise that external content in your answer. While additional documentation is worth linking to the answer itself should contain a full answer to the question itself, to guard against (inevitable) link-rot.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the hint, I updated the answer accordingly :)

Comment: thanks for your reference, a bit understand.. But how do i implement this in my code ? Can you help me ? @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni